# You don't have permission to edit this api key. required permission serviceusage.apikeys.update

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have been using Google Cloud Platform mainly to use it with Google Maps. I created several API keys which are working fine. The last one was a couple of weeks ago. A couple of days ago I wanted to updated it but couldn't, an error message was coming up very briefly when saving it.

I thought it might have been a glitch for that day. Today I tried again and I got the error again. The error says "You don't have permission to edit this api key. required permission serviceusage.apikeys.update"

To make things worse I can't update other API Keys neither.

I guess something has changed but I don't know what, any idea ?

[The message on the Google Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MifnP.jpg)

[The service appears to be enabled in Roles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5OYG.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the error message, the permission `serviceusage.apikeys.update` is needed if you want to update keys.

The IAM roles that have this permission included are the following:

- Owner
- Editor
- API Keys Admin

According to the screenshot attached, looks like the roles are enabled.

Could you confirm if your user have one of the roles mentioned above granted? You will be able to check it trough the UI in **IAM & Admin > IAM > Members**.

Otherwise, you can also check if you have granted any custom role with the permission `serviceusage.apikeys.update`. You will be able to check it through the UI in **IAM & Admin > IAM > Roles**.